# Xamarin.Android AlertDialog Show() get RuntimeException

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

I have an `Activity` (`ActivityA`) where user could click one item from the list and it will open the next `Activity` (`ActivityB`):

```
public class ActivityA : ReactiveAppCompatActivity<LoginViewModel>
    {
        ListView AvailableProjectListView;
        AvailableProjectAdapter ProjectAdapter;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AvailableProjects);

            AvailableProjectListView.Events().ItemClick
                                    .Subscribe(result => StartDownloadActivity(result.Position));
        }

        void StartDownloadActivity(int selectedProject)
        {
            //do some things here before open the next activity

            Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityB));
            StartActivity(downloadIntent);
        }
}
```

In the next `Activity` (`ActivityB`), I will show an `AlertDialog` if the download process is error:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel.DownloadStatusCode)
    .Where(x => x == APIRequestResult.UnknownError)
    .Subscribe(result =>
    {
        this.ViewModel.UserAction = LoginUserAction.None;
        ShowUnknownErrorAlert();
    });

void ShowUnknownErrorAlert()
{
    this.ViewModel.DownloadStatusCode = APIRequestResult.None;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.SetTitle(Resource.String.download_error);
    builder.SetMessage(Resource.String.please_try_again_later);
    builder.SetNegativeButton(Resource.String.ok, (senderAlert, args) => {
        var alert = senderAlert as AlertDialog;
        if (alert != null && alert.IsShowing)
        {
             alert.Dismiss();
        }
        Finish();
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.Create();
    dialog.Show();
}
```

The `AlertDialog` is working fine for the first time. But, after I open the `ActivityB` again from `ActivityA`, the alert dialog is not showing and there is this message:

> [Dialog] show mWindowManager.addView RuntimeException

What could possibly wrong?

Comment: Please include a full diagnostic error message.

Comment: there is no exception and the only message shown was: `[Dialog] show mWindowManager.addView RuntimeException`. @YorkShen-MSFT

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem, could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?